Save a btrfs disk after power failure?
I have a non-system 4TB Western Digital disk (WD4000F9YZ) with a sole btrfs partition that no longer shows up after a power failure.
I can see this in /var/syslog that it's struggling to do something while the system is booting up. This message appears every 2 seconds or so:
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.020913] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x20 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.020927] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.020932] ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.020936] ata2.00: cmd 60/20:28:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 5 ncq dma 16384 in
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.020936]          res 41/40:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.020947] ata2.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.020950] ata2.00: error: { UNC }
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.021717] ata2.00: ATA Identify Device Log not supported
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.022486] ata2.00: ATA Identify Device Log not supported
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.022495] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.022514] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=2s
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.022520] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.022523] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.022528] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#5 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.022530] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 4 prio class 0
Jul 16 23:44:50 test kernel: [  510.022552] ata2: EH complete

I've replaced cables and even tried putting the disk in a USB enclosure to see if I could pull it up on a different computer, but the disk partition doesn't come up.
Any ideas on how I can potentially recover? Or has the disk totally died? Can someone help me understand these errors?

Either please. Preferably recover the data.
